# How to prevent page from refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I need to catch refresh event in javascript/jquery. My whole page is being loaded by ajax, I mean all the links and all the forms on my page are being sent by ajax requests. Now, when user refreshes my page, this refresh event is breasking up all I wanted to achieve with my ajax requests, so I really need to catch user refresh calls and stop them, then just forward this refresh event as ajax call.

Is that even possible? And I don't want to catch the F5 keypress - that's insufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dYNf4/1/show/)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            return "are you sure to leave this page";
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: +1, Just note that this would of course come up in any instance of leaving the page (a link, back / forward, etc), but you can add your own way of at least shutting it off for normal links, etc

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible to block every form of refresh. Learn about the [HTML5 pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) so your users can refresh and use the back/forward buttons with ease.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the HTML5 History API is inconsistent  and buggy, in addition it is implemented differently in all the HTML5 browsers + incompatibility with HTML4 browsers.

Fortunately, History.js is good work that provides cross-compatibility for the HTML5 browsers (ensuring all the HTML5 browsers work as expected) and optionally provides a hash-fallback for HTML4 browsers (including maintained support for data, titles, pushState and replaceState functionality).